# Populating the table as per my requirement

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I am new in iOS developing. I am building a demo project where I have a TableView and a prototype cell. I have taken four image views in that cell. I have a group where I have 30 images. So, in my code I have taken an array to store the images. Now I want to populate my table in such a way that, in my TableView, there will be 8 rows. Each row will consist of 4 images, but the last row, that is the 8th row will be of 2 images.

But when I am running my code the last row is also showing 4 images instead of 2. Can anyone tell me where am I wrong? Thanks in advance.

This is my code...

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

 self.patternsArray = @[@"1.jpg",@"3.jpg",@"2.jpg",@"4.jpg",@"6.jpg",@"5.jpg",@"7.jpg",@"9.jpg",@"8.jpg",@"10.jpg",@"12.jpg",@"11.jpg",@"13.jpg",@"15.jpg",@"14.jpg",@"16.jpg", @"18.jpg",@"17.jpg",@"19.jpg",@"21.jpg",@"20.jpg",@"22.jpg",@"24.jpg",@"23.jpg", @"25.jpg",@"27.jpg",@"26.jpg",@"28.jpg",@"30.jpg",@"29.jpg"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableCell"];

UIImageView *imageView1 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

UIImageView *imageView2 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
imageView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+1]];

for (NSInteger i=0; i<=[self.patternsArray count]; i++) {
    UIImageView *imageView3 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
    imageView3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+2]];

    UIImageView *imageView4 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4];
    imageView4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+3]];
}

return cell;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{



return [self.patternsArray count]/3.75;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImageView *imageView1 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

UIImageView *imageView2 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
imageView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+1]];
if(indexPath.row != 7){

    UIImageView *imageView3 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
    imageView3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+2]];
    imageView3.hidden=NO;

    UIImageView *imageView4 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4];
    imageView4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+3]];
    imageView4.hidden=NO;

}
else
{
    UIImageView *imageView3 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
    imageView3.hidden=YES;

    UIImageView *imageView4 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4];
    imageView4.hidden=YES;
}
return cell;
}
```

for custom Images

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(indexPath.row !=7){
        UIImageView *imageView1 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
        imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        imageView1.hidden =NO;

        UIImageView *imageView2 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
        imageView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+1]];
        imageView2.hidden =NO;

        UIImageView *imageView3 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
        imageView3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+2]];
        imageView3.hidden=NO;

        UIImageView *imageView4 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4];
        imageView4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+3]];
        imageView4.hidden=NO;

    }
    else{
        if(patternsArray%4 == 1){
            UIImageView *imageView1 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
            imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            imageView1.hidden=NO;

            UIImageView *imageView2 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
            imageView2.hidden=YES;


            UIImageView *imageView3 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
            imageView3.hidden=YES;

            UIImageView *imageView4 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4];
            imageView4.hidden=YES;
        }
        else if (patternsArray%4 == 2){
            UIImageView *imageView1 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
            imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            imageView1.hidden=NO;

            UIImageView *imageView2 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
            imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+1]];
            imageView1.hidden=NO;

            UIImageView *imageView3 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
            imageView3.hidden=YES;

            UIImageView *imageView4 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4];
            imageView4.hidden=YES;
        }
        else if (patternsArray%4 == 3){
            UIImageView *imageView1 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
            imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            imageView1.hidden=NO;

            UIImageView *imageView2 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
            imageView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+1]];
            imageView2.hidden=NO;

            UIImageView *imageView3 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
            imageView3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+2]];
            imageView3.hidden=YES;

            UIImageView *imageView4 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4];
            imageView4.hidden=YES;
        }
        else{
            //you requirement
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No dude! 32 images are coming. Last row contains 4 images instead of 2. :( @Sumit

Comment: I have added this line `if(indexPath.row != 7){ }` it means for loop not work at the time when 8th row came in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I understood what you have done! But it's not working. :( @Sumit

Comment: clean the project and run again.

Comment: Not happening! :( @Sumit

Comment: Imageview 3 and 4 gone hidden in 2nd row.

Comment: Can you please get me understood what does the line mean?

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: More specifically this " forIndexPath:indexPath ".

Comment: `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` will always return a cell. It either re uses existing cells or creates a new one and returns if there are no cells.

While, the traditional `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` will return a cell if it exists i.e if there is a cell which can be reused it returns that else it returns nil. So you would have to write a condition to check for nil value as well.

Comment: One last question I want to ask you, if I leave the number of images part to user. Means user can add as many images as they want. Now what to do to populate the cell as per user's requirement like, if array count%4 = 1 then last 3 image views will be hidden, if array count%4 = 2 then last 2 image views will be hidden and array count%4 = 3 then the last image view will be hidden for the last row. Can you please help me in this case? @Sumit

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code, Simply hide image3 & image4 views in last row

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableCell"];

    UIImageView *imageView1 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.section * 4)+indexPath.row]];

    UIImageView *imageView2 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    imageView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.section * 4)+indexPath.row]];

    if(indexPath.row != 7){ {
        UIImageView *imageView3 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
        imageView3.image = [self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.section * 4)+indexPath.row];

        UIImageView *imageView4 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4];
        imageView4.image = [self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.section * 4)+indexPath.row];
        imageView3.hidden=NO;
        imageView4.hidden=NO;
    }
        else {
            UIImageView *imageView3 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
            UIImageView *imageView4 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4];
            imageView3.hidden=YES;
            imageView4.hidden=YES;
        }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: can you add your crash log ?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd4048'

Answer (score 0):

For the ones who are having requirements like mine this is the solution..

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

 self.patternsArray = @[@"1.jpg",@"3.jpg",@"2.jpg",@"4.jpg",@"6.jpg",@"5.jpg",@"7.jpg",@"9.jpg",@"8.jpg",@"10.jpg",@"12.jpg",@"11.jpg",@"13.jpg",@"15.jpg",@"14.jpg",@"16.jpg", @"18.jpg",@"17.jpg",@"19.jpg",@"21.jpg",@"20.jpg",@"22.jpg",@"24.jpg",@"23.jpg", @"25.jpg",@"27.jpg",@"26.jpg",@"28.jpg",@"30.jpg",@"29.jpg", @"31.jpg",@"32.jpg"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImageView *imageView1 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
UIImageView *imageView2 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
UIImageView *imageView3 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
UIImageView *imageView4 = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4];

if ([self.patternsArray count]%4 == 0) {
    imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    imageView1.hidden=NO;

    imageView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+1]];
    imageView2.hidden=NO;


    imageView3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+2]];
    imageView3.hidden=NO;

    imageView4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+3]];
    imageView4.hidden=NO;
}

else if([self.patternsArray count]%4 != 0 && indexPath.row != [self.patternsArray count]/4){
    imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    imageView1.hidden=NO;

    imageView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+1]];
    imageView2.hidden=NO;


    imageView3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+2]];
    imageView3.hidden=NO;

    imageView4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+3]];
    imageView4.hidden=NO;


}
else
{
    if ([self.patternsArray count]%4 == 1) {
        imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        imageView1.hidden=NO;
        imageView2.hidden=YES;
        imageView3.hidden=YES;
        imageView4.hidden=YES;
    }
    if ([self.patternsArray count]%4 == 2) {
        imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        imageView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+1]];
        imageView1.hidden=NO;
        imageView2.hidden=NO;
        imageView3.hidden=YES;
        imageView4.hidden=YES;
    }
    if ([self.patternsArray count]%4 == 3) {
        imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        imageView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+1]];
        imageView3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.patternsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+2]];
        imageView1.hidden=NO;
        imageView2.hidden=NO;
        imageView3.hidden=NO;
        imageView4.hidden=YES;
    }
}

return cell;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

if (_patternsArray.count % 4==0) {
    return _patternsArray.count/4;
}
return [self.patternsArray count]/4 + 1 ;

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```